# Improve security for a Wildly JSF project

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, firebase-authentication, wildfly

I'm trying to moving a local web project in JSF to a Wildly cloud. The authentication is made with this Firebase filter:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    userManagerSession = (UserManager) request.getSession().getAttribute("userManager");

    // managed bean name is exactly the session attribute name
    // boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().endsWith(LOGIN_PAGE);
    if (!request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/giocapp/s/")) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    String token = null;
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if (cookie.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)) {
                token = cookie.getValue();
                tokenCookie = cookie;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (token == null || token.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Missing token oauth2");
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + LOGIN_PAGE);
    } else {

        try {
            FirebaseToken decodedToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(token);

            account = new FirebaseAccount(decodedToken.getUid(), decodedToken.getName(), decodedToken.getEmail(),
                    decodedToken.getPicture());
            if (userManagerSession == null) {
                userManagerSession = userManager;
                userManagerSession.login(decodedToken.getUid());
            }
            System.out.println(userManager.getUserId());
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (FirebaseAuthException e) {
            System.out.println("Token oauth2 not valid");
            refreshToken(cookies, request, response, filterChain);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `login.xthml`:

```
<p:panel id="panel">
                <div class="ui-g-12">

                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                        <p:inputText id="user-name" value="#{userManager.userId}"
                            label="Username" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="Inserisci il nome utente" />
                        <label>Username</label>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <p:message for="user-name" display="icon" />
                </div>
                <div class="ui-g-12">
                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                        <p:password id="password" value="#{userManager.userPassword}"
                            label="Password" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="Inserisci la password" />
                        <label>Password</label>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <p:message for="password" display="icon" />
                </div>
                <div class="ui-g-12">
                    <p:captcha label="Captcha" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Accedi" icon="ui-icon-person"
                        action="#{userManager.login()}" update="panel messages" />
                    <p:button outcome="/s/dashboard" value="Password dimenticata"
                        icon="ui-icon-help" styleClass="secondary" />
                </div>
            </p:panel>
        </div>
```

I've implemented the `captcha`; is this a good approach to reduce possibile security problem? I'm using firebase authentication with strong password!
The idea is to place this project into the Google Cloud Platform or to open the 80 e 443 port into my firewall, in order to let WAN access. Also I want to use let's encrypt in order to use http(s) over TLS/SSL to improve encryption.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using some sort of standard authentication?  Any time you roll your own you risk missing something.  Standards, like normal JEE security, have been tested over the years and more likely to be secure.  And the only purpose of a captcha is to reduce the chance of an automated login.  It does not add any security per se.

Comment: I'm using Firebase Authentication and the login method to filter the request. The captcha is just to reduce the automated login and the http(s) to encrypt the message. By the way I'm using the header authentication so I think the captcha can be skipped; isn't it?Is there some brute force settings to be prevented in Wildly?

Comment: And your actual coding question is?

Comment: The code just show how my filter is working and may be useful for someone who wants to help to improve security! @Kukeltje

Comment: Then you should have created a question and answer. Questions are not 'blogs'

Comment: @Kukeltje I think the questions is not difficult to understand: are the lines of code provided safe? If you can help you know where the keyboard stands, whereas may be someone who can help!

Comment: So you want a coding advice? I thought you meant your code was helpful to others... Then I'm with the initial comment. Don't implement your own security layer, even if it is with an authentication framework. Authentication is only a small part of full security and this question is higly open for opinionated answers and those are 'off-topic' for stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you! I know it is a good way not to implement an own security layer, but even if I use a framework layout, some lines of codes should be implemented and that way I post them. By the way do these lines of code implement correctly the firebase authentication framework? Can be safe to use it?

Comment: No idea, I don't use firebase. So it would take too much time to digg into. And mostly you 'configure' the frameworks when using them for security, very little coding then.

Comment: I'm with you, but the problem that I don't find to much information about JSF and Firebase! So I've implemented something more than a few lines of code